# Netbeans can't compile C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, netbeans

I can't compile anything in C in netbeans, because of this:

```
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.c
gcc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S and multiple compilations
```

All google returns is http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40227. What should I do? Where I can change settings passed to compiler?
Netbeans 7.1.2

Comment: Assuming you have "make", you could write your own makefile.  And then just have Eclipse create a new project of the type "C/C++ project with Existing Sources".  You just point this project to your Makefile.

Comment: I'd be more curious to know why MinGW can't handle that command line, where gcc/g++ certainly can. I'm not booted into my windows partition to test this out... maybe later.

Answer (score 0):

Installing pascal after mingw and adding it to path caused netbeans to use make from pascal bin instead of msys.